# Long-running Seed method with Entity Framework code-first

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

My `Seed()` method is getting rather long-running.  Is there a way to write to the console whilst running the `update-database` command?

So far, `Console.WriteLine()` and `Debug.WriteLine()` have not written output to the Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid run-on seed methods by extending the base DbContext class with a method that accepts an interface and returns the context instance to keep things fluent.

Though it doesn't solve the issue of not being able to write console/debug output in the package manager console, it will tell you which entity that you failed on while keeping things tidy.

**Configuration.cs**

```cs
using System.Configuration;
using MySolution.Data.Migrations.Seedings;

namespace MySolution.Data.Migrations
{
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MySolution.Data.MySolutionContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MySolution.Data.MySolutionContext context)
        {

            context
                .AppendSeeding<AddressSeeding>(true)
                .AppendSeeding<CustomerSeeding>(true)
                .AppendSeeding<OrderSeeding>(true)
                .AppendSeeding<ShipmentSeeding>(true)
                .AppendSeeding<ApplicationSettingsSeeding>();

        }
    }
}
```

**DbContextExtensions.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MySolution.Data.Migrations {
    public static class DbContextExtensions {

        public static DbContext AppendSeeding<T>(
            this DbContext context, bool saveChanges = false) 
            where  T : ISeeding, new() {

            var seeding = new T();

            try {
                seeding.Seed(context);
                if (saveChanges) {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(
                    $"Unhandled exception while appending seed data via {seeding.GetType().Name}",
                    ex);
            }

            return context;

        }

    }
}
```

**ISeeding.cs**

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MySolution.Data.Migrations {
    public interface ISeeding {
        void Seed(DbContext context);
    }
}
```

**AddressSeeding.cs (Example implementation of ISeeding)**

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using MySolution.Data.Models;

namespace MySolution.Data.Migrations.Seedings {
    public class AddressSeeding : ISeeding {
        public void Seed(DbContext context) {

            ((MySolutionContext)context).Address.AddOrUpdate(
               address => new { address.Address1},
                new Address {
                    Address1 = "111 Fake St.",
                    City = "Nowhereland",
                    County = "Countyville",
                    State = "ST",
                    Zip = "12345",
                    AddressType = new AddressType {
                        Name = "Home"
                    },
                }    
            );

        }
    }
}
```